# How to change class names once and it's applied in HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css, class, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code, is it possible to change a class name for instance only in the CSS file and this change is also applied in the HTML document? or vice verse, changing the class name in HTML and seeing it change in the CSS file.

Answer (score 3):

At the time of writing, this feature does not exist in VS Code.

VS Code is currently unable to know if the same CSS class is referenced in other files, so refactoring across multiple files wouldn’t work.

If you have your cursor on a CSS selector and you press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> to find all references, you will find references to the class name only within the same CSS file, even when you are using the class in your HTML.

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/47331) for implementing cross-file IntelliSense for CSS classes and ids. This might lead to supporting refactoring across HTML and CSS files in the future.

Comment: cool, Shift+F2 didn't work for me but when I tried F2 it allowed me to type in a new name and then this applied across the whole css file. also the link didn't work, I am getting: This page is taking way too long to load.

Comment: @ZeWorks I fixed the link, it should work now. I also fixed a typo in the shortcut, it's not Shift + F2 but Shift + F12

Answer (score 1):

Full disclosure, I don't use Visual Studio, but a quick search looked like this is what you may be looking for? 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Zignd.html-css-class-completion

Unless I'm misreading?

Comment: Hi pj100, I meant what hb20007 talked about above.